# I use onclick function on submit but form action is not responding

Tags: javascript, php

here is function

```
function myFunction(button) {
    var oldValue = button.value;

    button.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    button.value = '...processing...';

    setTimeout(function () {
        button.value = oldValue;
        button.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }, 3000)
}
```

and here is form-

```
<form id="addform" action="index.php/adminuser/insert_state" method="post">

    <div class="form-group">
        Contact Number    
        <input type="text" required="" name="contact" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" id="submit" onclick="myFunction(this)">Submit </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

but form action is not working...please help me how to use disabled button and form action in a single form..

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Where the code for form action?

Comment: What is not working, and why are you using native javascript... Consider using jQuery or some other framework that simplifies the stuff

Comment: form action is not working

Comment: <form id="addform" action="index.php/adminuser/insert_state" method="post">

    <div class="form-group">
        Contact Number    
        <input type="text" required="" name="contact" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" id="submit" onclick="myFunction(this)">Submit </button>
    </div>
</form>

Comment: If you set the disabled attribute I believe it should look like this `button.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');` or you can use `button.disabled=true;` **/** `button.disabled=false;` **also** your javascript will not run because once the form is submitted the page will redirect to `index.php/adminuser/insert_state` with the form data. To run your javascript function you will want to use `event.preventDefault();` and use ajax to send the form data to your php file.